# Android: dialog vs nested layout performance

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, dialog

My app is quite complex, i have a lot of views and viewgroups.
I have already turned some of the nested linearlayouts into relativelayouts, but the tree is still quite deep.

In the views tree there are branches that i need to display only sometimes, i would like to know what performs better: a sub-tree to show and hide or a dialog?

Here's a rough image i've done to try to explain:
[image]

Image clearly shows: 4 views is better than 7, but what if i hide (gone) viewgroup #5?
How heavy is opening/managing a "complex" dialog?

What are the pros and cons?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested layouts is not recommended because of performance issues.

> Well some layouts can only be made by doing some level of nesting. But you should avoid having too many nested LinearLayouts and even more important NEVER nest LinearLayouts with weights. You can read a little more about optimizing layouts in the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/optimizing-layout.html).

Personally I use LinearLayouts for simple stuff and start using RelativeLayout when the layout gets more complex. So, my suggestion would be to use the dialog. It will also help in making the code easier to read.